# load text from String array and set text to textview is very slow in big string array

Tags: android

**hi
why load text from String array and set text to textview is very slow in big string array?**

please help to me.

```
 //get khotbe text from database and copy to khotbe activity
private void setkhotbetextarabicfarsi() {
    this.sqliteDB = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(this.getDatabasePath("aliname").getPath(), (SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory) null);

    Itemid = this.getIntent().getIntExtra("selectedFromListid", 1);
    Cursor cursorLines = this.sqliteDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM khotbe where IDFehrest=" + this.Itemid , (String[]) null);
    allrecs = cursorLines.getCount();
    matn = new String[allrecs];

    if (this.allrecs != 0) {
        cursorLines.moveToFirst();

        for (int i = 0; i < this.allrecs; ++i) {
            String TextArabicOfKhotbe = cursorLines.getString(cursorLines.getColumnIndex("TextArabicOfKhotbe"));
            int IDkhotbe = cursorLines.getInt(cursorLines.getColumnIndex("IDkhotbe"));


            this.matn[i] = TextArabicOfKhotbe;           

            cursorLines.moveToNext();
        }
    }
```

**and main code:**

```
 for(int var1 = 0; var1 < this.allrecs; ++var1) {

            tvArabic = new JustifiedTextView(this);

            tvArabic.setText(matn[var1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

you are creating the textviews in loop that might making it slow.. try populating the array values using an adapter..

Also check the number of rows you are accessing from the DB. if they are huge in number, they would require more time to be fetched.
Use limit in that case.